# Combining AJAX JSON to PHP/MySQL? php://input?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

Both the AJAX/PHP CODE works if tested individually, The AJAX sends the data to an API,
The PHP Sends the JSON info from a JSON file

What I want is the AJAX to send the JSON data to the PHP which will then be added to the database

*script.js*

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/userabc/friends', //LINK OF THE PHP HERE?
      data: {name: 'Person3', age: 67},
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Friend added!"+ data);
      }
});
```

*file.php*

```
// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('json.json'); // php://input?

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get the employee details
$id = $data['id'];
$name = $data['name'];
$email = $data['email'];
//insert into mysql table

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(id, name, email) VALUES('$id', '$name', '$email')";
$con->query($sql);
```

I tried inserting the `url:  http://localhost/WEP/JQUERYAJAX/mysl/php.php` 
to *script.js*
AND `php://input` to the *file.php* but didnt work? What can be the solution?

Comment: So how could I implement it?

Comment: added example with json conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on client:

```
var data = {name: 'Person3', age: 67};
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/WEP/JQUERYAJAX/mysl/php.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
      window.alert("Friend added! "+ data);
    }
});
```

And this on server side in php.php:

```
$_POST ? '' : $_POST = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
var_dump($_POST);
```

The alert will be:

```
Friend added! array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Person3"
  ["age"]=>
  int(67)
}
```

This means your php.php correctry parced json data and you may access it as $_POST['name'] and $_POST['age'] in your php.php. Use empty php.php without any other code (only those to lines that I've posted in this answer) in it to test script and be sure that you avoid any other errors.

Comment: In response to that i get "NULL"

Comment: The actual URL is: `url: 'http://localhost/WEP/JQUERYAJAX/mysl/php.php',`

Comment: open your web debugger (for example firebug) and check server response. it will include dump of your $_POST array.

Comment: or use your 'success: function (data) {...}' in ajax client script to alert it. this is simple.

Comment: IT alerts the message in an ARRAY but it doesnt get to the PHP file, why is that?

Comment: I dont get anything in the console, or the network panel, on the PHP file

Comment: Im able to send data that is defined in the PHP file, by click on the button one the client side(html file) but thats all i can do the connection i made from the client to the server

Comment: I've added more descriptions to my answer. Just copied it from answer then pasted and run on my localhost. Everything works correctly.

Comment: Im doing everything you say and doenst work, can it be because of XAMPP?

Comment: what certain message do you get inside of your alert window?

Comment: Friend added! array(2){
["name"]=>
string(7)"Person3"
["age"]=>
int(67)}
    The alert is ok, 
And in teh PHP I get a nice  NULL

Comment: If you get correct alert then all that left for you is only to put $_POST['name'] and $_POST['age'] to your database as you wanted it. and you may erase line with var_dump() because you don't need it in your code since you have ensured that your json data been parced correctly.

Comment: it's var_dump() that choes null in your browser when you try to access php.php directly from browser because your browser sends GET request and $_POST is NULL in this case.

Comment: Last question, can you tell me what does this code do exactly?
`$_POST ? '' : $_POST = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true); `

What is $_POST ? '' : $_POST? what is the question mark, and the colon, and what is 'true'?

Comment: If there is a $_POST superglobal array (means that your post input has been parced correctly) it does nothing. Otherwise it reads raw php input, trims trailing spaces and decodes data treating it as a json to associative (second 'true' param is for it) array. So you should be sure that you provide it with a correct json string or something that can be parced correctly by default.

Comment: Also script with this line is not expected to work otherwise than with post requests. If you want to use it for both get and post then you probably should use this line inside of if-else control structure built around $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].

Comment: But what is this code?
`$_POST ? '' : $_POST =...` it sounds like an if statement from your explanation

Comment: 1: The `? : ` syntax?
2: Why cant the AJAX code set the $_POST superglobal correctly? and POSTMAN can

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary
I suggest you to read manual at php.net carefully. There you'll find detailed answers on all of your questions.

Comment: I get the syntax now, just converted it into an IF statement, but this manual isnt about AJAX not setting the $_POST superglobal, there is nothing about it here, can you tell me why is that?